# Unsure what the symbol means and can't find anything online for it

Tags: notation, terminology

I have a [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jGk75.png) of a symbol that I don't know the meaning of and wasn't able to find an answer for on https://byjus.com/maths/math-symbols/. Any help would be appreciated. I know using mathjax is the preferred method but since I don't know what the symbols name is, I can't really type it up in mathjax.

Comment: $\mathbb{E}$ is typed as `\mathbb{E}`.  Lots of help here: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expected_value

Comment: @David Thank you!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.